# How do I collect text variables with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to make a bot that can collect words from Vocabulary.com, and I dont know how to grab the text from from the page, and then store it as a variable in python 2.7. This is what I have as of right now:

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver


chromedriver = "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get("https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/raise#")

Word1 = browser.find_element_by_class_name('dynamictext')
```

I don't know what I should copy from inspect element, so I'm going to past everything.

```
//*[@id="dictionaryContent"]/div/h1
#dictionaryContent > div > h1
<h1 class="dynamictext">raise<a data-audio="R/13JE699JC2AJ8" class="audio"></a></h1>
```

Comment: `Word1.text` should give it to you

Comment: "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'txt'

Comment: if the word "raise" is already in your URL, why do you need to scrap the page?

Comment: @KirilS. This was just something I could practice before I put it in the main program.